# How to properly manage objects when using StreamWriter/Reader with TcpClient?

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm developing software that communicates with external hardware via ethernet (TCP), and I'm experiencing difficulties regarding the object management (StreamWriter/-Reader and TcpClient). There will be frequent/continual communication between the computer and the hardware, which includes various commands.

My questions are:

1. When using TcpClient - does the connection/stream close or otherwise "reset" upon creating a new instance of TcpClient, for use in various classes - communicating with the same device? Or does it not matter unless I explicitly say .Close()?
2. How do I use StreamWriter/-Reader properly when two whole classes use both objects? Global declaration, or declarations for every method?
3. How does StreamReader.ReadLine() work? I have a peculiar case where it returns an "old" message, rather than the slightly newer it should. How can I properly use StreamReader such that each command will get their respective replies?

Comment: Its recommended to use using for objects that implements dispose.

Comment: 1 question per question please.

Comment: @spender It's because they are heavily related to one another, and basically one big problem divided into pieces so that it's possible to answer. I'm just looking to understand it better.